# How to find address on an element of linked list?

Tags: linked-list

If the address of the 8th element in a linked list of integers is 1022, then what is the address of 9th element and 15th element??

Explain in detail with example!!

I am really lazy, please do my homework for me.

thanx

Comment: Do you know how linked-lists work?  What part can't you figure out yourself?

Comment: So this *is* a trick question, right? Or am I just completely useless?

Comment: You want us to write your code for you, right? I'm sorry, but it doesn't work like that here. You have to try something on your own, _then_ come back if you encounter problems. Not the other way around.

Comment: t->next and t->next->next->next->next->next->next->next. Easy game!

Comment: You again? Why don't you go do your homework?

Comment: I like how he got quality answers despite the outcry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no relation between the addresses of the elements of a linked list, each element may be located anywhere in memory. To find your answer, you must traverse the list until you get to the 9th or 15th element and take the address.

Or, in most languages and implementations of a linked list, you could traverse to the 8th or 14th element and note that the value of the "next element" pointer is the address of the next element.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you have link list struct:

```
typedef struct tag_link {
   int data;
   tag_link* next;
} linked;

linked* eleventh; // points to 8th element
int* data_of_nineth = &(eleventh->next->data); // address of data of 9th element of list
linked* nineth = eleventh->next;               // address of 9th element of list
```

To get address of data in 15th element is best way to walt through `next` pointers until you find 15th element of linked list and then get address of what you want.